# Security Domination

Tags: security

Does Lower / Weaker Security Rule over Higher security or Vice Verse?

**E.g.**

A User wants to **Edit** a list and has the following permissions across two groups:
S1 - View Only
S2 - Full Access

Which security settings take precedence?

Now let's say he has permissions in multiple groups... and multiple Lists/Document Libraries, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The highest permissions granted to the user (or a group the user is member of) at any given level (Web, List, ListItem etc.) will rule. So, the user will get the highest permission given to him/her